# twitter widget wrap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter, jcarousel

i've created a live tweet feed onto my site which a want wrapped in a carousel. the challenge i'm facing is converting the twitter API feed divs into "li's" so each twitter feed is displayed in a seperate li.

> [click here](http://thisiswired.com/test/test.html)

I've been doing so reading into the following;

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

however i'm finding it hard to digest. Is there anyone in this forum that can kindly breakdown the development process to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: are you using the search api to retrieve those tweets?

Comment: i'm using this https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Comment: hmm, I've made a scrolling twitter widget that fetches tweets using the search api, I think there is a plug in for what you are trying to do because I remember finding it but because it didn't use the search api I couldn't use / convert it to what I needed. I will have a look for it now

Comment: Try this: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/archives/2011/06/24/how-to-create-a-scrolling-twitter-feed-using-jquery/

Comment: that link you sent me, isn't what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: ok, perhaps you should update your question since that link gives you a carousel of tweets, yes, you would need to modify the css but aside from that I don't see why you can't make use of it.

Comment: I am after a carousel of tweets, at present the javascript for the twitter widget forms new tweets in a div tag. i need to create a javascript function which converts new tweets to for a li. A plugin is one option but i'll rather add the few lines of javascript so i can learn for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped out on your other question so im assuming you're wanting to apply this to the same url - http://thisiswired.com/test/test.html?

If that's the case you can use the following code:

```
// Remove unwanted div
$('.twtr-reference-tweet').remove();

// Change the <div>s to <li>s
$('.twtr-tweet').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<li id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'">' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
});

// Change the parent <div> to <ul> and wrap it in a <div> ready to apply the carousel
$('.twtr-tweets').replaceWith('<div id="carouselId"> <ul class="twtr-tweets">'+$('.twtr-tweets').html()+'</ul></div>');
```

Sorted!